# How do I write a Visio macro to to move a shape from one layer to another?

Tags: vba, visio

I'm using Visio 2003 and I would like to write a macro that will move the selected items to a hidden layer called "Deleted Items".

I tried recording a macro and all I got was this, which doesn't even show me how to interact with layers. :(

```
Sub Move_to_Delete_Layer()
'
' Moves the selected item(s) to the "zDeleted Items" Layer (which typically remains hidden). This is basically an "undo-able" way to delete the item.
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+d
'

    Dim UndoScopeID1 As Long
    UndoScopeID1 = Application.BeginUndoScope("Layer")
    Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID(175).CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowLayerMem, visLayerMember).FormulaU = """9"""
    Application.EndUndoScope UndoScopeID1, True

End Sub
```

Edit:

Thanks. The SDK helps a little, but unfortunately not enough to produce working code. I think what I want to do is essentially

```
Dim myLayer As Visio.Layer
Set myLayer = Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Layers.Add("Deleted Items")
myLayer.Add Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.ContainingShape, 1
```

But that code doesn't work. It gives me an error that says "Run-time error '-2032465766 (86db089a)': Requested operation is presently disabled"

And I also want to remove the shape from any layers it was already in. I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Sorry don't have Visio 2003 but you may find [Visio 2003 SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa272275(v=office.11).aspx) useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Layers are pretty straightforward in VBA:
This will remove all layer memberships from a page:

```
dim i as integer
for i = ShpObj.LayerCount to 1 Step -1
    dim Lay as Visio.Layer
    set Lay = ShpObj.Layer(i)
    Lay.Remove ShpObj
next
```

This will add a shape to your delete layer

```
Dim myLayer As Visio.Layer
Set myLayer = Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Layers.Add("Deleted Items")
myLayer.Add Application.ActiveWindow.Selection(1), 1
```